# How to display an image using wizard

Tags: api, winapi, user-interface, wizard

I am developing a visual c++ application and i have to display an image on wizard (i have choosen wizard particularly because i have to create a button interface which on clicking should show different files on  the same window of wizard where i want to show the image)i know the image display mechanism because i have already displayed an image on preview pane(even i have created buttons on that using resource editor but the problem is that when i display different files on the same window the buttons disappears and only appears by hovering ouse over them because button handle is the parent handle for every file display so it disappears and the first sight but appears by hovering mouse over them ) .
So for this reason i wanted to display the image and different files on wizard where the same window is used to display files on different button click so that the button will persist on the wizard for each display.

How to achieve my target ?  Anhy ideas ?
please do not hesitate to ask me if there is any confusion in my question.

here are the screen shot of what i want to achieve http://prntscr.com/1mbife and http://prntscr.com/1mbijf on different button clicks but it just to show you that what i want but here my problem is when i click on "previous" button then it shows an image but the "next" button don't appear until i move mouse over it , see this picture http://prntscr.com/1mbiyj it don't contain the Next button until i move mose over it. so in order to solve this problem i want to acieve the same by using wizard. The problem is how to acieve using this wizard ?

Comment: I'm having real trouble understanding the question just from your description. Perhaps it would help if you [edit]ed in your code and a screenshot.

Comment: @code gray please see the above last paragraph and see the snapshots on the links. I have just edited.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is in the black rectangle containing the buttons. From your description, it seems that it's painted over the buttons, erasing their appearance, and the button is "invisible" until you force its repaint by hovering over it.

So you simply need to fix the drawing of the rectangle. How exactly? Well, it really depends on how you draw it and why.